# asyncio behavior in jupyter vs script

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    video_id = url.split('/')[-2]
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = await response.text()
        async with aiofiles.open(f'{video_id}.json', 'w') as f:
            await f.write(data)


async def main(loop, urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = generate_links()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await main(loop, links)
```

The script runs smoothly in the Jupyter notebook but it won't run from within a `.py` script due to `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`.

I'm trying to understand what is happening here and why this is the case.

Comment: I'd assume it happens because your code runs inside some function in jupyter. `await main()` should be changed to `asyncio.run(main())`, to run code successfully. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: @Galunid, I already tried that setup (ie. `asyncio.run(main(loop, links))`
 but it throws: `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`

Comment: The short answer is that Jupyter rewrites your code so that it works for the common case (namely using ``asyncio``), the reason being convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else trying to figure it out, Galunid's tip was spot on. The issue has been the way the loop object has been used. Removing it from within the `ClientSession()` forces the client to use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` as default.

The final form is given below.

```
async def fetch(session, link):
    video_id = link.split('/')[-2]
    async with session.get(link) as response:
        data = await response.text()
        async with aiofiles.open(f'{video_id}.json', 'w') as f:
            await f.write(data)


async def main(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: 
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = generate_links()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.run(main(links))
```

Jupyter notebooks make use of this idea to handle the loop event in the background, allowing one to `await` the result directly.