# Using asyncio to send the same data to 3 separate endpoints via post request in python

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm having a hard time using asyncio to send the same data payload to 3 separate endpoints. Mind you these are post requests. I'm new to asyncio so please bare with me. Since I have 3 different endpoints (all of which are using the same data payload), I thought using `loop.run_in_executor` would work.

Here's my sample code:

```
import asyncio
import requests

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    model1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda : requests.post(url = url1, 
                                                              json = sample_data, 
                                                              headers = header1))
    
    model2 = loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda : requests.post(url = url2, 
                                                              json = sample_data, 
                                                              headers = header2))
    
    model3 = loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda : requests.post(url = url3, 
                                                               json = sample_data, 
                                                               headers = header3))
    
    model1_response = await model1
    model2_response = await model2
    model3_response = await model3

    #print(dir(model1_response)) 
    
tm1 = time.perf_counter()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

tm2 = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Total time elapsed: {tm2-tm1:0.2f} seconds')
```

I doubt I cracked the surface of this since I'm getting error `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`. Please help

Comment: Are you running Jupyter notebook?  If so, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319320/asyncio-behavior-in-jupyter-vs-script.  Otherwise please indicate the exact line of code that's triggering the RuntimeError, preferably by giving the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `asyncio.gather()` to run the tasks concurrently:

```py
import time
import asyncio

import requests

url1 = 'https://www.google.com'
url2 = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
url3 = 'https://www.yahoo.com'

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    model1 = loop.run_in_executor(
        None, lambda: requests.get(url=url1)
    )

    model2 = loop.run_in_executor(
        None, lambda: requests.get(url=url2)
    )

    model3 = loop.run_in_executor(
        None, lambda: requests.get(url=url3)
    )

    responses = await asyncio.gather(model1, model2, model3)
    for r in responses:
        print(r.text[:10])  # print first 10 characters from each response

tm1 = time.perf_counter()

asyncio.run(main())

tm2 = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Total time elapsed: {tm2-tm1:0.2f} seconds")
```

Prints:

```
<!doctype 
<!DOCTYPE 
<!doctype 
Total time elapsed: 0.67 seconds
```

---

**Note:** I'd recommend to using asynchronous library for HTTP requests such as [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/) instead of `requests`.